# wp Event Manager booking status Processing(Authorizenet AIM)

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with Membership and Events. I am using Paid Membership Pro for memberships and Event manager Pro for events. I am using Authorize-net payment gateway and most event bookings are successful.

But I can see some booking in the Admin with the status Processing(Authorizenet AIM).

I have log to the Authorizenet and there is no processing transaction for this booking.

Could you please help me to solve this. What is the reason for that status?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have SSL enabled for you site otherwise this will not work. Events manager will always force the https connection if a booking form accepting Authorize.net is used.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It already have SSL. And most of the transactions were success. Only very few of them getting this error..

Answer (score 0):

Wideload Shipping may be correct here, if you don't have a valid SSL certificate or SSL enabled then the booking process won't work with Authorize.net since you must be able to send card info securely.

I'd suggest you ask this on our pro forums, as a pro customer we'd be happy to help you troubleshoot there. If you supply us a link we can also probably have a better idea about what's going wrong and provide you with further steps to remedy the issue.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply and I have valid SSL certificate and most of the transactions are OK and few of them showing like this.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this same behavior starting to happen on my Events Manager Pro as well. Seemingly randomly some bookings will show "Processing (Auth.net)" while others show "Completed" (as they should).

From this thread's suggestion, I took a look at my https URLs. I found that sometime in the last month, we ran an update that has inserted some link hrefs and other unsecured URLs in the source code.

I had been using HTTPS plugin to force https on the events pages, but since the site URL was http only, it was pulling in these "external" files as http. I noticed in Firefox that my SSL connection showed broken. While in Chrome, it felt it was secure. My GUESS at this time is that the ones that go thru are where the page in the browser looks to be secure. While the ones that only get "Processing" are happening on the broken SSL browser views.

I've now changed my site URL to https as the base URL which ensures Wordpress uses it throughout. I now don't get a broken SSL in Firefox. My presumption is that this will fix this issue. Time will tell. I'll come back to update IF I'm wrong. But hopefully that might help for you to look at URLs, such as wp-json and other link rel URLs.

Of note, it seems the credit cards ARE authorizing/captured for those transactions. So it's more likely the return trip from Auth.net for the silent URL to changes the status of the booking?